# Windows Store App activation request error

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm getting below error message when I run my windows store 8.1 application.

I'm facing this error message for specific application not for every windows 8.1 store apps.

[image]

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/ro-RO/7fe6e9e7-54ee-479b-8b5f-c7e1b6ecccd8/error-after-linking-to-store-app-this-app-does-not-support-the-contract-specified-or-is-not?forum=winappswithcsharp

Answer (score 0):

App started running after I done the below steps.

1). Start screen
2). Store
3). Settings
4). Your account
5). sync with login credentials